# Geocoder sometimes return address as null

Tags: android-intent

I am trying to retrieve address using geocoder on the basis of longitude and latitude.Sometimes i see that it throws IOException saying "Service not available" and return address as null. Below is my code for the same:

```
public Address getAddress(double lat, double lng){
        if(Constants.LOCAL_LOG)Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "CustomLocationManager : getAddress() START");
        Address address = null;
        if(Geocoder.isPresent()){
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(mContext);
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                if(addresses != null && addresses.isEmpty() == false){
                    address = addresses.get(0);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
        if(Constants.LOCAL_LOG)Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, "CustomLocationManager : getAddress() END");
        return address;
    }
```

What are the conditions when IOException is thrown and "Service is not available" comes.

Let me know how this can be fixed. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime google does not provide address for some locations .  i have tested it when i was creating a geo - fencing application.

So when you get the address. check for the null values

Answer (score 0):

its better to use a NETWORK_PROVIDER location instead of GPS_PROVIDER to get the address correct in reverse geo coding

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```